# Convergence of an improprer integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

For which $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ does

$$ \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\log x^2 +3}{x^\alpha(12\log^4x + 7 \log^2x + 1)} \,dx$$

converge?

In particular, how do I use the function $g(x) = 1/x^\alpha$ to study it?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: change the variable : $u=\log x$ gives you a very simple way to conclude.

Comment: The integrand ins't even defined throughout the range of the integral.
$\log^{k+1} x$ is only defined where $\log^k x$ is positive.
More specifically, for $k\geq 1$ we have that $\log^k$ is defined on $(\exp^{k-1}(0),+\infty)$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri My bad. It is defined for $x \geq 1$

Comment: @Fimpellizieri  The notation $\log^k(x)$ as used here means $(\log(x))^k$, not the $k$th composite.

Comment: @MarkViola Is this usual notation? The only situation I usually see $f^k(x)$ to mean $f(x)^k$ is for trigonometric functions, and personally I avoid it because I value consistency.

Comment: I've seen it used persuasively on the logarithm function .  But, I've also seen that notation used to mean composite functions too.